# My jquery Animation doesn't work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get my animation to work on after an ajax call has been made. It works fine when the user lands on the page. But if the user navigates back to the front page the animation will not run. I'm pretty new to Jquery, could you give me some hints?

I think it has something to do about `.on` but I'm not sure about the syntax if so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quoteName");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(3000)
            .delay(12000)
            .fadeOut(3000, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you call showNextQuote() after you have executed your AJAX request?

Comment: paste here the code where you are attaching .on callback. also what jQuery version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have an Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
(function() {

})();
```

every variable and function declaration you put inside (like `showNextQuote()`) will not be accessible from other functions outside of it.

```
(function() {
    function showNextQuote(arg) {
         alert( arg );
    }
    showNextQuote('A');
})();

showNextQuote('B'); // ReferenceError: showNextQuote is not defined
```

One other thing is that your `var quotes = $(".quoteName");` selector might get no results cause the DOM was not ready to be parsed by JS and for jQuery to catch your elements.

```
jQuery( function($) { // DOM is now ready and the $ alias secured.

    var quotes = $(".quoteName"); 
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).fadeIn(3000).delay(12000)
                                          .fadeOut(3000, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();

    // other functions here

    $('selector').on('some event', 'dynamicSelector', function(){
          showNextQuote(); // will work
          // other stuff here?...
    });

});
```

Another hint would be that if you populate your DOM with new elements you might want to re-catch them to update the `quotes.length`

Comment: awesome thanx  guys you've bee a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, when you make that AJAX call, you update (and by that I mean removing the current DOM nodes contained in the quotes object and creating new ones). If you do this, when you anitame the nodes in the quotes object, nothing will happen, becauser they no longer belong to the DOM you're seeing. jQuery objects don't have 'live updates', they don't change to reflect the changes in your DOM.
What you need is to make this call again after your AJAX request completes, to update the quotes object:

```
quotes = $('.quoteName');
```

Of course, your 'quotes' object is not global, so you might not be able to update it if your AJAX call is not inside the scope of the anonymous function where you're defining the code you've posted.

Comment: awesome thanx guys you've bee a big help :)